# how to trigger click event on href element with lightbox plugin?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, triggers, click, lightbox

I am trying to trigger click event on hyperlink with jquery like the way below. This hiperlink show lightbox with image (rel="lightbox").

```
$(document).ready(function () {  $('a').trigger('click'); });
```

The function above is not working. This is the hyperlink

```
<a href="a.jpg" rel="lightbox">hyperlink anchor</a>
```

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: When your code is executed the lightbox plugin probably hasn't attached itself to it.  Can you link to a page where we can see this and play with it?